# How to make search query for all index except some of them in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to ask how to make search query for all index except some of them in elasticsearch. I mean as an example,
Indexes have same start pattern like

> Italy_*

Some of indexes like

```
Italy_rome_*
Italy_turin_*
Italy_palermo_*
...
```

Some are like below

```
Italy_people_*
```

I want to make search query in python for indexes that have city name like an Index= 'Italy_*'
but I don't want the any other types of indexes. I mean not making search query on Italy_people. Below is my code, how to improve it for this purpose ? Thanks for answering.

```
       es.search(
            index='Italy_*',
            scroll='2m',
            size=size,
            body=body
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is using like below

```
index= 'Italy_*, -Italy_people_*'
```